# Karate: How to implement --no-sandbox header for linux usage with sudo

Tags: karate

I want to setup a headless chrome driver for UI Test Automation in jenkins.

But to run the test command

```
sudo -E java -jar karate-0.9.3.jar karate_GUI.feature
```

I have to run as root and it requires --no-sandbox, which, if I'm not wrong, it's still not supported in v0.9.3.

If possible, how can I include --no-sandbox option?

I checked https://intuit.github.io/karate/karate-core/ and there is no --no-sandbox option.

My feature configuration:

```
Feature: message end-point
Background:
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', executable: '/usr/bin/google-chrome', headless: true }
# Login Url
* def browserManagementUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/login/'

Scenario: GUI Testing for Login page
    Given driver browserManagementUrl
    And eval driver.input('input[name=name]', 'admin')
    And eval driver.input('input[name=password]', 'adminadmin')
    And driver.submit('#login-button')
    When driver.submit('#login-button')
    Then match driver.location == 'http://localhost:8000/select/'
```

The linux command and it's results

```
sudo -E java -jar karate-0.9.3.jar karate_GUI.feature
```

```
07:15:56.296 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Main - Karate version: 0.9.3
07:15:57.345 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] WARN  com.intuit.karate - skipping bootstrap configuration: could not find or read file: classpath:karate-config.js
07:15:57.418 [chrome_1560323757416] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - command: [/usr/bin/google-chrome, --remote-debugging-port=9222, --no-first-run, --user-data-dir=/var/jenkins_home/workspace/my-karate_GUI@2/integrations/target/chrome_1560323757416, --disable-popup-blocking, --headless]
07:15:57.419 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - poll attempt #0 for port to be ready - localhost:9222
07:15:57.420 [chrome_1560323757416] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - env PATH: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
07:15:57.423 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - sleeping for millis: 250
07:15:57.674 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - poll attempt #1 for port to be ready - localhost:9222
07:15:57.675 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - sleeping for millis: 250
07:15:57.793 [chrome_1560323757416] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - [0612/071557.791933:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
07:15:57.810 [chrome_1560323757416] DEBUG c.intuit.karate.shell.CommandThread - command complete, exit code: 1 - [/usr/bin/google-chrome, --remote-debugging-port=9222, --no-first-run, --user-data-dir=/var/jenkins_home/workspace/my-karate_GUI@2/integrations/target/chrome_1560323757416, --disable-popup-blocking, --headless]
07:15:57.926 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - poll attempt #2 for port to be ready - localhost:9222
07:15:57.927 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - sleeping for millis: 250
07:15:58.178 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - poll attempt #3 for port to be ready - localhost:9222
[...]
07:16:02.206 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - poll attempt #19 for port to be ready - localhost:9222
07:16:02.207 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - sleeping for millis: 250
07:16:02.848 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - request:
1 > GET http://localhost:9222/json
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Host: localhost:9222
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_212)

07:16:02.862 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused), http call failed after 13 milliseconds for URL: http://localhost:9222/json
07:16:02.863 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR c.i.k.driver.chrome_1560323757416 - http request failed:
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
07:16:02.918 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - <<fail>> feature 1 of 1: karate_GUI.feature
---------------------------------------------------------
feature: karate_GUI.feature
report: target/karate_GUI.json
scenarios:  1 | passed:  0 | failed:  1 | time: 5.4993
---------------------------------------------------------
Karate version: 0.9.3
======================================================
elapsed:   6.39 | threads:    1 | thread time: 5.50
features:     1 | ignored:    0 | efficiency: 0.86
scenarios:    1 | passed:     0 | failed: 1
======================================================
failed features:
karate_GUI: karate_GUI.feature:8 -
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Exception in thread "main" picocli.CommandLine$ExecutionException: there are test failures
    at com.intuit.karate.Main$1.handleExecutionException(Main.java:133)
    at picocli.CommandLine.parseWithHandlers(CommandLine.java:1157)
    at com.intuit.karate.Main.main(Main.java:139)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you do know that the UI automation pieces are still experimental and yes I don't think we support `--no-sandbox` - feel free to open a ticket and help us with some links to why this is needed, what it does etc.

A suggested workaround is you can pass a batch file as the `executable` key to the [`configure driver`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver) call. In this batch file you can then call the chromedriver executable with whatever custom parameters or arguments you need.

Do let us know if that works. It also sounds to me that a way to pass any custom flags is a needed feature, do add this to your feature request.

EDIT: for those landing here in future, I'm not 100% sure, but maybe the info here will help: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1134#issuecomment-638990087